Cannot proxy port on WSL
I'm currently trying to configure Cassandra in WSL but it cannot establish a connection (ERROR: cannot bind to MY_PUBLIC_IP:7000).
To solve this I did two things : I now have port redirection from my public IP to my local windows IP (using port 7000 and 9042) and I followed David Bombal's guide to have a port redirection from my local windows IP to my WSL2 IP.
The command I used (for the second redirection) was netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=7000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=7000 connectaddress=MY_WSL_IP in PowerShell (I also tried listenaddress=MY_WINDOWS_PRIVATE_IP).
After those two changes, I did some networking tests using ncat. The results are as follows :

When the second port redirection is not active and I have ncat -lvp 7000 running in PowerShell (on windows), I can establish a connection from an another machine (can be inside or outside of my local network).
When I have nc -lvp 7000 running in WSL, I can establish a connection from windows on the same machine

Sadly, when both port redirections are up and I have nc -lvp 7000 running in WSL, I can't establish a connection from an outside machine (Ncat: TIMEOUT) making me think that maybe David Bombal's guide doesn't apply here ?
For the record I also tried the mirrored networking configuration but that didn't work either.
What could I do to redirect ports from my windows IP to WSL ?
